# Gnome: Rebind top-left corner window spread?

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I enjoy the window spread function(which is why i went from unity to Gnome 3), however I would like it re-binded to the top-right corner rather than top-left.

How do I change this?

I tried the Hot-Corn-Dog extension without luck.

Thanks in advance!